# Load module dynamically in angularJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-module

How can I load module script dynamically.

I have 2 JS files:

```
module1.js

(function() {
    var mod = angular.module('module1', []);
    ....
})();
```

This is the second:

```
module2.js

(function() {
    var mod = angular.module('module2', ['module1']);
    ....
})();
```

I want to load the module1.js dynamically when it is required in module2.js.

There are any way to "map" modules name with the source URL? Something like this:

```
angular.registerModuleSource('module1', 'http://myhost.com/app/module1.js')
angular.registerModuleSource('module2', 'http://myhost.com/app/module2.js')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for this purpose.

[Here is a good article on how to do it.](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Use require.js for this purpose. So you can load modules at run time.

Link--http://requirejs.org/